# Google Cloud Datalab setup process was unable to deploy App Engine application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I followed the steps to get started with Google Cloud Datalab.

The setup failed at this error:

`Oct 14 09:20:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript: 
Oct 14 09:20:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript: env_variables:
Oct 14 09:20:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript:   DATALAB_ANALYTICS_ID: UA-54894152-3
Oct 14 09:20:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript: -------End of app.yaml------
Oct 14 09:20:26 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript: Start deploying...
Oct 14 09:20:28 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript: You are about to deploy the following modules:
Oct 14 09:20:28 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript:  - team-marvel-sandbox/datalab/main  From: [/datalab/app.yaml]
Oct 14 09:20:28 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [404]:
Oct 14 09:20:28 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript:   This application does not exist (app_id=u'team-marvel-sandbox').
Oct 14 09:20:28 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript: ['_HTTPError__super_init', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', 'args', 'close', 'code', 'errno', 'filename', 'fileno', 'fp', 'getcode', 'geturl', 'hdrs', 'headers', 'info', 'message', 'msg', 'next', 'read', 'readline', 'readlines', 'reason', 'strerror', 'url']
Oct 14 09:20:28 datalab-deploy-main-20151014-09-18-39 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module failed.`

I tried a solution by deploying a empty skeleton application to App Engine and re-run the setup. It failed again with the same error.

Anybody has any experience dealing with this?

Comment: Can you share your project id ... we'll see if we can roll out a fix for this project sooner?

Comment: @nikhilk team-marvel-sandbox

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue and it happens to certain projects. While the fix is on the way, the only workaround so far is to try deploying it into another project.

Comment: as expected. it's a beta!

Answer (score 1):

When your project was created, what is the App Engine location (in advanced options) you picked? Datalab depends on managed VM, which is only supported in US only. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/.

Comment: it is located in us-central. i tried again. This time it returns a 403 error. I ran the cloud datalab deployer using the google account that is the owner of the cloud project.

Comment: For the 403 error, check out the solution here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583437/datalab-cloud-deployment-403-error/33638271?noredirect=1#comment55101848_33638271