# DataLab Cloud Deployment 403 Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to deploy DataLab. Have confirmed my project is in a US zone. I've tried creating new projects and deploying there, to no avail. It appears everything works properly up to this point. Important to note, my project ID does not have the preceeding s~ (unsure if that matters or if it's simply a notation used in DataLab / Google Cloud. I have tried ~10 times over the course of two days with no success.

```
Nov  7 13:32:06 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-13-29-51 startupscript: Verifying that Managed VMs are enabled and ready.
Nov  7 13:32:06 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-13-29-51 startupscript: If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...#015If this is your first deployment, this may take a while...done.
Nov  7 13:32:06 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-13-29-51 startupscript: WARNING: If this is your first deployment, please try again.
Nov  7 13:32:06 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-13-29-51 startupscript: ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Server responded with code [403]:
Nov  7 13:32:06 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-13-29-51 startupscript:   Forbidden Unexpected HTTP status 403.
Nov  7 13:32:06 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-13-29-51 startupscript:   You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~datawranglingtest').
Nov  7 13:32:07 datalab-deploy-main-20151107-13-29-51 startupscript: Step deploy datalab module failed.
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue (the three checks did not show any problems) for project dlab2-1122. This occurred for projects in both us-central and us-east.

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems the permissions list are not synced between Developer Console and AppEngine. Try the following:

1. Go to Developer Console. Permissions page.
2. In the service account list, copy the account which looks like "******-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com" to another place, and we'll use that later.
3. Make sure it disappears from the list. Then add the account back and make sure it has "Can edit" permissions.
4. Wait for a few minutes and try deploying Datalab again.

Meanwhile, the issue is probably project specific. If possible, you may also try it on a new project.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks Bradley! Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear that. A few quick checks/questions --

1. Is your project billing enabled? This is needed for being able to instantiate managed VM instances within the project.
2. Are you a member of either the owners/editors groups within the project?
3. Is the Compute Engine API enabled. Specifically check on the status of the API at https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/compute_component/overview?project=datawranglingtest

If these don't help, please let us know, and I'll get someone to look into your specific project.

The s~ prefix is used within AppEngine, and shouldn't be the source of this.

Comment: Thanks @nikhilk! (1) Billing is enabled, but I'm on a free Cloud trial. Is that a problem? (2) I am the owner of each project (3) Compute Engine API is enabled, and I can launch Compute Engine VMs within my project. Do let me know if you need any more information, and I'd appreciate help with fixing it. Thanks!

Comment: Would love to get this resolved, as I was hoping to present this tool in 5 days at a conference... :)